# Mod Rewrite tweak to ignore asset directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm configuring Expression Engine on Windows using IIS and have ISAPI v3 Rewrite installed.

It's partly working. The main site and subpages work but needs to be modified because some web page assets are stored in similarly named directories.

The recommended Rewrite provided by Ellislabs [is this](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/remove_index.php.html) and I've modified it a little to work with our Win 2012 IIS 8 server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) abc/$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ abc/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

For example, the URL http://oursite.example.com/abc works.

Subpages are mostly working and I suspect this applies to any page really but I'm noticing it on subpages.  It removes index.php and mostly loads, such as http://oursite.example.com/abc/subdept/page/

However our developer has some assets kept in a server directory named /uploads/abc/ so if a page refers to this directory, it fails to load those assets because it contains the same name, "abc".

Thus, what is the best way to handle this?

I'm guessing I can either tell it to ignore "uploads/cls" or correct the current Rewrite so that it only looks at the first "abc".  I'd like for the solution to cover most similar issues that would arise so I don't have to keep modifying it. We have 12 sites and I'll have to apply the solution to each one.

Everything I've tried hasn't worked.

Also, I thought !-f and !-d would tell it to ignore it if the file or directory existed and that doesn't seem to be working as I'd expect here because these images in /uploads/abc/ do exists.

Thanks!

--

Additionally just trying to get it to work at all, I tried adding a htaccess file with "RewriteEngine Off" in the /uploads/abc/ directory and that failed to fix it.

I also tried to add this after each comment and it fails to fix it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/excluded-folder/.*$
```

Seeing how both of the above attempts fail to fix it, I'm wondering if there could be something else going on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My rewrite was fine. The problem turned out to be code within an Expression Engine template that the in house developer created. They updated the code and the images are loading fine now.